# How to pin the battery saver to the start menu?

Tags: pin-to-start

I would like to have a toggle for the battery saver mode feature, but I don't think it's possible at this stage.
Perhaps someone knows better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to achieve what you want.

But since GDR-3 apps can offer to your the possibility to pin the screen rotation and the battery saver mode.

It's just a link to the feature and you still need to toggle the button.

One app I can remember do this is [Insider from DAONE](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/insider/d9b7989e-1592-4f25-a556-4755c06bf2e9) (DISCLAIMER: I use the app but I'm not related to this and/or know who is responsible for)

Comment: Thanks, it seems like all the shortcut type apps have got it now too!

Comment: Search for Windows Phone insider tool in the store it has lots if shortcuts

Comment: I have this app, I like it for the news! But I don't see any shortcuts? "Windows Phone Insider"

Comment: Windows Phone Insider(Microsoft Corporation) is different from Insider(DAONE)